# Can electron/positron vacuum bubbles interact with vacuum photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum, virtual-particles

The proposed Feynman diagram below represents two electrons exchanging photons with an electron/positron vacuum bubble which itself exchanges a photon with the electromagnetic vacuum.

Is this diagram valid?

I presume that it cannot form part of a QED calculation of coherent electron scattering as the vacuum photon forms an extra input into the diagram which breaks coherence. Is this correct?

Does the electron/positron bubble become a "real" fluctuation due to its "measurement" by the EM vacuum photon?

[image: vaccum bubble interaction]

Comment: "Does the electron/positron bubble become a "real" fluctuation due to its "measurement" by the EM vacuum photon?" - Is this not answered by a comment to your recent question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/716647/a-simple-argument-that-an-electric-field-causes-the-vacuum-to-emit-photons ?

Comment: [Furry theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furry%27s_theorem)